# Toshiba Satellite L755 screen upgrade

Tags: laptop

My Toshiba Satellite L755 has a HD resolution screen, so I want to upgrade it a Full HD resolution panel.

Is it possible and how do I even search for such a panel(like does it have different no. of pins, etc ?)...links to amazon.in or aliexpress would be appreciated.

Comment: You'd start by checking whether your exact model / frame of laptop was offered with a screen you're interested in.
It's likely not worth the effort for a 8 year old machine - it'd be cheaper to sell it, and buy a comparable laptop with a screen you like.

Comment: @towe no it was not offered with a Full HD screen but the graphics is capable of running a full HD resolution screen. How would it be cheaper to sell this i7 laptop and get a new one ?